# "IsHidden" attribute for sharepoint groups ("com.apple.sharepoint.group.*.plist")

Tags: user-account, sharing, group, macos

On my macOS 11 Big Sur, there are several groups titled "com.apple.sharepoint.group.*.plist" (where * is a number starting from 1 and increasing).
What I understand - they are related to shared folders (a single shared folder equals new group with such name).
What I don't understand - these groups, when created, have an attribute **"dsAttrTypeNative:IsHidden: 1"**. I don't get what this actually hides them from. If I manually set it to 0, they are still not visible in "Users&Groups", and if this attribute is at 1, they are visible anyway when listing groups with **"id -Gn"** command or through **dscl**. So what gives?
I've checked other groups, and they don't have the "IsHidden" attribute by default.